# KVM - advanced network parameters (like network interface bandwidth, setting max transfer rate for emulated network card)

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, kvm

I need some info about advanced KVM network parameters. By advanced I mean the onces that are not accesible form GUI.
Something like:

- network interface bandwidth
- setting max transfer rate for emulated
  network card

Are there any? I've had hard time googling for them

Answer (score 1):

Emulated cards run with tap/macvtap interfaces from Linux. That's where you can set/query the parameters of the interface. For more gory details about tap interfaces & qemu you can read [this post](http://blog.alantan.com/2007/01/qemu-tap-bridge-network-configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Above link given by dtatulea is really good.